# transfer yii site to new server

Tags: php, yii2

Premise: I am not a coder.

I would like to move my site which has been made using yii (not by me) to another host.
Before going on with the domain transfer I want to make sure it'll work fine, so I made a copy of all directories and files, I first tried to test it on my local pc (wamp environment), and all I get is the list of directories and files, thinking the problem was with my setup I uploaded all in a subdirectory on live site, and here again all I get is the list of directories and files.

I created a database, and imported the database, and then edited `../common/config/main-local.php` like this:

```
'db' => [
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=newdb',
'username' => 'newdb_username',
'password' => 'new_db_psw',
'charset' => 'utf8',
],
```

In the `requirements.php` these are the warnings:

> PDO SQLite extension Warning All DB-related classes Required for
>   SQLite database. PDO PostgreSQL extension Warning All DB-related
>   classes Required for PostgreSQL database. Memcache extension Warning
>   MemCache APC extension Warning ApcCache Expose PHP Warning Security
>   reasons "expose_php" should be disabled at php.ini

What am I missing, what else do I need to change?

Thank you

=========

**EDIT** 10 sep 2015

I had to go back to `php 5.4.32` as `5.5.18` created problems with the main site.

New error log:

> [09-Sep-2015 22:51:24 Europe/London] 32767
>  [09-Sep-2015 22:51:24
>   Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'yii\base\InvalidParamException' with message 'The directory does not
>   exist: /var/chroot/home/content/20/5481254/html/frontend/' in
>   /home/user4563/public_html/prova/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:224
>   Stack trace:
>   #0
>   /home/user4563/public_html/prova/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(358):
>   yii\base\Module->setBasePath('/var/chroot/hom...')
>   #1
>   /home/user4563/public_html/prova/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(223):
>   yii\base\Application->setBasePath('/var/chroot/hom...')
>   #2
>   /home/user4563/public_html/prova/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(202):
>   yii\base\Application->preInit(Array)
>   #3
>   /home/user4563/public_html/prova/frontend/web/index.php(29):
>   yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
>   #4 {main}
>    thrown in
>   /home/user4563/public_html/prova/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php
>   on line 224

I guess I need to edit some path somewhere, but where??

Comment: It seems your `basePath` has been hard-coded according to previous environment. Search for that particular config in config files.

Comment: I suggest you to check `frontend/config/main.php` and make sure `'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),` is not altered.

Answer (score 0):

As long you don't use PDO SQLite, PDO PostgreSQL, Memcache and APCcache in your yii application this should not be a problem. "What you don't use you don't need". You use mysql and for mysql there's no warning so there's no db issue.

The only thing you should do is to disable "expose_php" in the php.ini

EDIT:
Also remember that yii2 needs at least php 5.4. See the documentation at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-intro-yii.html#requirements-and-prerequisites

Comment: Thank you, yes I thought so. Sorry for not being very clear, my problem is that the site is not showing, and only the directories and files are displayed, I need to know what is blocking the site to display. As extra info if I go to frontend/web/index.php it is a blank page.

Comment: it looks more like a php or server configuration problem

Comment: write error_log(E_ALL); in top of the index.php. Do you have an php error.log? What does it says?

Comment: Thanks. When adding error_log(E_ALL); (frontend/web/index.php) I still get a blank page (I suppose it goes after <?php). The error.php in frontend/web reports these: [09-Sep-2015 15:09:09 Europe/London] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /path-to-yii-subdirectory/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php on line 25 ----- [09-Sep-2015 15:09:09 Europe/London] 30719

Comment: Line 25 is this: spl_autoload_register(['Yii', 'autoload'], true, true);

Comment: Okay that's because your php version does'nt support []  as array definition. You need php > 5.4. See the documentation on http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-intro-yii.html

Comment: Php version is 5.4.32

Comment: That's strange. Because the error is because your php doesn't support short arrays. Can you just put `echo phpversion();` on top of index.php and see if 5.4.32 is really the used version.

Comment: I need to talk to host, cpanel reports 5.4.32 phpversion reports 5.3.29

Comment: Actually no need to, I just discovered I can switch to 5.5.18 from cpanel, which I did, indeed phpversion reports that, unfortunatelly the problem is still there: no site.